# How can I resize QMessageBox?

Tags: c++, qt, qmessagebox

I have a `QMessageBox` which I'd like it to be bigger. It's a simple `QMessageBox` with two standard buttons, Ok and Cancel. The problem is that it is very small for my application's purposes. Code shows like this:

```
QMessageBox msg;
msg.setText("Whatever");
msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Ok | QMessageBox::Cancel);
msg.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Expanding);

int ret = msg.exec();
switch (ret) {
  case QMessageBox::Ok:
      ui->textEdit->clear();
      break;
  case QMessageBox::Cancel:
      break;}
```

I tried several ways to increase the size:

```
msg.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Expanding);

msg.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Maximum,QSizePolicy::Maximum);

msg.setFixedHeight(600);
msg.setFixedWidth(600);
```

I even cleared and rebuilt, and it compiles everything but nothing take effect...

Do you have any idea on how to set QMessageBox size "by hand"? Thanks.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can edit the css of the label:

```
msg.setStyleSheet("QLabel{min-width: 700px;}");
```

You can similarly edit the css of the buttons to add a margin or make them bigger.

For example:

```
msg.setStyleSheet("QLabel{min-width:500 px; font-size: 24px;} QPushButton{ width:250px; font-size: 18px; }");
```

There is also a [trick mentioned](https://forum.qt.io/topic/24213/qmessagebox-too-small/10):

```
QSpacerItem* horizontalSpacer = new QSpacerItem(800, 0, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
QGridLayout* layout = (QGridLayout*)msg.layout();
layout->addItem(horizontalSpacer, layout->rowCount(), 0, 1, layout->columnCount());
```

But this doesn't seem to work for everyone.

Comment: Yes, that's the solution. But now buttons and text display are out of scale. How can I increase both to be proportionate?

Comment: It works better with height `msg.setStyleSheet("QLabel{height: 300px; min-height: 300px; max-height: 300px;}");`

Comment: @DYangu edited with another css example added to change the size of the buttons. You can play with the css, but without a precise result in mind I can't give anything more specific.

Comment: @DYangu see my answer for another solution which might fix this.

Answer (score 10):

coyotte508's answer caused my layout to be horribly off center and at different widths it was cut off. In searching around further I found [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/22298-QMessageBox-Controlling-the-width) thread which explains a better solution.

In essence the layout of a messagebox is a grid, so you can add a SpacerItem to it to control the width. Here's the c++ code sample from that link:

```
QMessageBox msgBox;
QSpacerItem* horizontalSpacer = new QSpacerItem(500, 0, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
msgBox.setText( "SomText" );
QGridLayout* layout = (QGridLayout*)msgBox.layout();
layout->addItem(horizontalSpacer, layout->rowCount(), 0, 1, layout->columnCount());
msgBox.exec();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can subclass `QMessageBox` and reimplement resize event handler as following:

```
void MyMessageBox::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *Event)
{
    QMessageBox::resizeEvent(Event);
    this->setFixedWidth(myFixedWidth);
    this->setFixedHeight(myFixedHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted my QMessageBox width to adapt in proportion to the length of the text content with a certain amount of buffer to avoid line wrap.  After surveying numerous forums and threads including this one, I came up with:

```
int x_offset = (2.0 * MainWindow::geometry().x());
int y_offset = (0.5 * MainWindow::geometry().y());
msgBox.setText(vers_msg.data());
QSpacerItem* horizontalSpacer = new QSpacerItem 
    (8 * vers_msg.size(), 0,
    QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::Expanding);
QGridLayout* layout = (QGridLayout*)msgBox.layout();
layout->addItem(horizontalSpacer, layout->rowCount(),
    0, 1, layout->columnCount());
msgBox.setGeometry(
    MainWindow::geometry().x() + x_offset,
    MainWindow::geometry().y() + y_offset,
    msgBox.geometry().width(),
    msgBox.geometry().height());
```

Adjust the hard numbers in x_offset, y_offset and horizontalSpacer to suit your situation.  I was hoping it would be easier than this but at least this works.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the "inspect the Qt source code and adapt" approach, this worked for me with Qt 5.12:

```
if (auto grid = dynamic_cast<QGridLayout*>(msgBox.layout())) {
    if (auto text = grid->itemAtPosition(0, grid->columnCount() - 1); text && text->widget()) {
        text->widget()->setFixedWidth(500);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, of course, that this will break if ever they change the way they do layouts of QMessageBox.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and easy way:

```
msg_box.findChild(QLabel, "qt_msgbox_label").setFixedWidth(600)
```

Instead of 600, calculate the width as needed for your content!