# How to display a subprocess output in PyQt5?

Tags: ubuntu, subprocess, pyqt5

```
def on3_click(self):
    subprocess.call('ip a',shell=True)
```

Hello so this `clicked.connect` pointer allows me to print out my desktop ip address using `ip a`command but it will only print out in the terminal. How can I display the output of the subprocess in a QMessageBox or other GUI window ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could collect the output of the subprocess call as a string and then just open a QMessageBox.

```
class Template(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        btn = QPushButton('Button', self)
        btn.clicked.connect(self.on3_click)

    def on3_click(self):
        ip = str(subprocess.call('ip a', shell=True))
        QMessageBox.information(self, 'Info', ip)
```

Comment: wow thank you that work it turnes out that my syntax is somehow upside down . Anyways is there a way to resize a QMessageBox ?

Comment: Check out this post, it has a good answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37668820/how-can-i-resize-qmessagebox