# How to resize QMessageBox in qt c++?

Tags: c++, qt

I need to resize a detailedText window in QMessageBox. How can I do this? I`m resizing a messageBox like this:

***msgBox->setStyleSheet("QLabel{min-height: 1000px;}");***

But it is not working on detailedText window.

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37668820/how-can-i-resize-qmessagebox?

Comment: Yes. I got the code from here

Comment: Is it better to create your own message window? This way you can customize everything without complicated tricks